# How can I import data from a REST call, json feed into a SQLite database on a MAC?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, macos, sqlite, xamarin

I have data that's on my server in a SQL Server database. I can access that with a REST call into a C# ASP.Net Web.API that I have control over and it will return json data. Possibly I can get that to return other formats of data but I am not sure about that.  I have full access to the server application and the json it creates.

On my development Mac I am using DB Browser for SQLite and Xamarin to develop a multi-platform app. I have a small SQLite database created.

How can I import/insert the JSON data from some of my tables on the server to tables in the SQLite database that I create on my MAC? I need to do this manually but I would like to automate the process of doing the import into a bash script or something similar that I can run with a command.

I have researched this but don't seem to be able to find any examples of how to do it so I opened up a bounty in the hope that someone could give an answer that would be a big help to me and to others.

Comment: This really seems like the ultimate "please do my work for me" question and it doesn't even seem to be from a student. And of course I must add the classic SO question: "what have you tried?" In general, the generic simple solution is to pull the data down in JSON, convert it to SQL insert statements and execute those against SQLite.

Comment: I have tried researching this on the internet and not been able to find anything at all or any examples of how this would normally be done. What method would you suggest for converting the JSON to SQL and executing those on a MAC. I have only experience of running code in Windows PowerShell and would like suggestions on how this could be done on the MAC.

Comment: Fair enough, although I still believe the scope of this question is well beyond the intended StackOverflow purpose. FWIW, I would consider using Node.js, particularly if you have any Javascript familiarity at all. It is suitable for the task, and there are lots of examples of the individual portions of the task. I also think you will get more responses with a language tag.

Comment: FYI - very coincidental timing - I have not read the whole story, but based on where you said your skills are, would this (Powershell on OSX) be helpful news? http://www.winbeta.org/news/now-open-source-cross-platform-powershell-appears-github-windows-linux-osx

Comment: @Alan are you trying to do an initial import or a continual update?

Comment: @valdetero - Initial import and then a week later redo the database and do another "initial import".  The amount of data would not be large so I feel I could do a complete refresh each time.

Comment: rest, json and sqlite, that's something that php would solve with few lines

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you have two options that you can do:

- Make a simple Xamarin.Mac app that does this. Similar to how windows folks might make a console app. Just have it have one button and call pretty much the same code in your xamarin app to download the data and dump it into a sqlite db.
- A better option, would be to write a "unit test" (or integration test for those hardcore peeps) that calls the **existing** code in your xamarin app and writes it to a sqlite db on the file share. Then you can do this as often as you want with a run of a unit test. This could be done in your test runner in Xamarin Studio (Visual Studio or anything that has a test runner). I would use either nUnit or xUnit since they great cross-platform support.

In my previous app, I had XUnit tests that checked to make sure the API calls were working and other tests to ensure that my SQLite.Net-PCL code was working. You could combine that into a single "test" to download the data into a db3.

This assumes you abstracted your code out. If not, you could just copy and paste it. Either way, if you are using x-plat nuget packages the code will work on desktop or mobile app.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions.  I'll start looking into those today.

Answer (score 4):

i would use node js to write a script using javascript.

install nodejs. https://nodejs.org/en/download/ or

```
brew install node
```

create a directory to work on your project
mkdir myimporter
cd myimporter

install the required libraries in the folder

```
npm install --save request sqlite3 moment 

npm install -g nodemon
```

open the folder or app.js with your favorite text editor

save the following code as app.js

```
var request = require('request');
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var moment = require("moment");
var url =  'http://www.google.com';
var s, e;



var fs = require("fs");
var file = "test.db";
//var file = process.env.CLOUD_DIR + "/" + "test.db";
var exists = fs.existsSync(file);
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);

// use same exists from checking if db exists, with assumption that table would exists in a new db.
if(!exists){
    db.run("CREATE TABLE Stuff (thing TEXT)");
}


function saveResultTosqlite3(message){
    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO Stuff VALUES (?)");
    stmt.run(message);
    stmt.finalize();
}


s = moment();
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    e = moment();
    var elapsed =e.diff(s,'milliseconds');
    var responseCode = response.statusCode;     

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {    
        console.log("successful request");
    }
    var message = 'request to ' + url + ' returned status code of ' + responseCode.toString() + ' in ' +elapsed.toString() + ' milliseconds'  ;
    console.log(message);
    saveResultTosqlite3(message);    
});
```

run the follwing terminal to run the script each time it changes, for development / testing

```
nodemon app.js
```